# How to get a count in mongodb for approved users

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I need count for a approved = true users on `mongodb`.

```
 Users.count #it showing total users count from db
```

I tried  `Users.count({:approved => true})`

But it showing wrong number of arguments ( 1 for 0 )

Help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is right one.

User.where(:approved => true).count

Answer (score 3):

try

```
db.user.where({:approved => true}).count()
```

Comment: And in Mongoid, it would look like `User.where(:approved => true).count`.

Comment: User.where(:approved => true).count this is right one. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find()` before `count()`:

```
db.orders.find( { ord_dt: { $gt: new Date('01/01/2012') } } ).count()
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/#cursor.count

Answer (score 0):

Similar to user3415653 answer:

```
db.user.count({'approved' : true})
```

its somewhat easier ;)